# Download Files from Print Button using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, get

I am downloading patient files from our current electronic health record company. Unfortunately, they do not have a mass export button, so I am currently having to manually download each encounter, which will end up consisting of me getting thousands of files (and eventually carpel tunnel). I would appreciate anything you can do to help me speed this up using python script.

How it works:

- I login with my credentials to the chart website, which is HTTPS.
- I locate a patient chart (which takes me to one URL that lists all of the visits a patient has had (each "encounter")).
- From there, I click on one, which sends me to another webpage that consists of information from that encounter.
- Next, I click on the "Print" button which downloads a PDF for that visit (the button actually takes me to a link: https://myehrcompany.com/charts/encounters/printEncounter/3309 that automatically downloads the PDF).
- Finally, I go back to the big list and do the next one. Once I finish all of the encounters, I simply drag the PDFs I downloaded into a file I have for that patient before moving on to the next patient.

It may be worth noting that each encounter is numbered irrespective of the patient. So, encounter 3309 could be Joe's 10th visit to us and 3310 could be Ellen's first.

Thank you for any and all help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use selenium for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.yourwebsite.com")
username_field = driver.find_element_by_name("username") #Find the name/id/class of the username field, you can change find_element_by to either class or id or xpath whatever u need
username_field.send_keys("yourusername")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password") #Find the name/id/class of the password field, you can change find_element_by to either class or id or xpath whatever u need
password_field.send_keys("yourpassword")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close()
```

After logging in, you'd have to do the rest based on how the website looks like and basically click with selenium on the print button, wait for the PDF to download and move to the rest of the links.